# Typescript ReturnType issue

Tags: typescript

Im trying to get the correct return type based on the method key of an interface. Typescript is showing an issue here but i cant work out why.

```js
interface Provider {
  reboot?(a: string): (string | null)[]
  cc?(): Promise<string>
}
type ProviderReturn<K extends keyof Provider> = ReturnType<Provider[K]>
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgApQPYDdgBNrIDeAUMslBAEYYZgD8AFHAFzIDOYUoA5gJSsMOXEN2QAfZCACuAGxm8A2gF1SyBAkb80mALbA2EADxCeAPmIBfYmACeABxTpseaACUIYKVBCGA0sggAD0gQXDZkAGsIGwwYbWd8KFNkAF5kd09vABV7IyccRIVfJVMgA)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your interface defines an object with 2 potentially undefined methods. `ReturnType` does not work on `undefined`

You can do follwing with `Nonnullable`

```
interface Provider {
  reboot?(a: string): (string | null)[]
  cc?(): Promise<string>
}
type ProviderReturn<K extends keyof Provider> = ReturnType<NonNullable<Provider[K]>>
```

If the optional part matters, you can use a conditional type :

```
interface Provider {
  reboot?(a: string): (string | null)[]
  cc?(): Promise<string>
  foo(): string
}

type ProviderReturn<K extends keyof Provider> = undefined extends Provider[K] ? ReturnType<NonNullable<Provider[K]>> | undefined : ReturnType<NonNullable<Provider[K]>>

type a = ProviderReturn<'reboot'> // (string | null)[] | null; 
type b = ProviderReturn<'foo'> // string
```

Comment: I think it worth adding `NonNullable` option. [Example](https://tsplay.dev/NDPpzN)